# key aware hazelcast queue

Tags: java, queue, hazelcast

Is there any way we can have key aware operations on a Hazelcast queue?

So for example, I would have multiple consumers on a queue and would expect 'similar' type of messages to be processed on the same member node every time. A behaviour that is normally achieved by local entry listeners on imaps.

Comment: Can you post what you've tried so far?

Comment: @greg currently we are using a map with local entry listeners. A particular property of the object model is set as a string key, so we know the models are distributed key wise. The processings can thus be handled locally. This map doesn't store the data and we have configured it that way. I wanted to get this behaviour using a distributed blocking queue instead.